# Why am I only getting a partial image? (libGDX,sprite,spriteBatch)

Tags: java, libgdx

Question summary at the bottom.

This is supper simple code, but clearly I don't understand what is going on in this library.  When I load a circle image in libGDX using this code:

```
public class LevelTest extends ApplicationAdapter implements GestureListener, InputProcessor{
Sprite maze;
SpriteBatch batch;
Texture mazeImage;

@Override
public void create(){
    mazeImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("maze.png"));
    maze = new Sprite(mazeImage);
    maze.setPosition(100, 100);
    maze.setSize(70, 70);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
}

@Override
public void render(){
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    //batch.draw(maze, 0, 0, maze.getOriginX(), maze.getOriginY());
    maze.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}
```

it is only showing me a quarter of the circle image.  it should be a full circle maze, but instead shows only the top right 1/4th of the image.

This is what it shows:
[image: quarter picture]

Interestingly if I change the image size from 70,70 to 100, 100  it appears to take random portions of the image in stripes  and flip them to the opposite side of the image.  So I end up with overlapping, striped, mirrored,  1/4 images like so:

[image: jittery image]

3.
I tried using a .jpg instead and instead of showing black lines the lines where transparent.  (see below).  I fixed this by making a negative of the image (changing black lines to white ones) but I would still like to know why libGDX is making the black part transparent.

[image: jpg black is transparant]

1. how do I get the whole image to show up as PNG?
2. what the heck is causing the image to stutter and mirror portions of itself as a PNG?
3. why are the colors for a JPG inverted (black shows white and white shows black)

Thanks in advance for your help with any of these questions.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot?

Comment: the site won't let me until I have 10 reputation points :(

Comment: I think I can get you over that limit :)

Comment: Two possibilities: 1) You possibly updated your Libgdx version but forgot to update the native code. (not an issue if you're using Gradle). 2) The PNG file is not encoded properly. How are you generating the PNG file?

Comment: @Tenfour04 The problem was #2 thank you all for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out that the .png image that I was using was not encoded properly.  I had used a web site called "Lunapic"  to change the white to a transparency. Thanks to Tenfour04, I downloaded Gimp and used it to make the white parts transparent and the images all worked in libGDX the way that they are supposed to.